# Pros and cons of installing UV sanitizer light in HVAC

Tags: hvac, safety, uv-exposure

I am  looking to improve indoor air quality of a home. I have heard UV light can be use to sanitize against certain organisms.

Does it "kill" mold and viruses floating in the circulating air?

What are the main safety aspects of installation to watch out for? How to reduce radiation in home? Does it increase ozone?

Can every HVAC system be retrofitted with one?

For a 10-year old electrical attic system does it make sense to install this or should I buy a new one with the UV component ?

Comment: There are a multitude of questions here which doesn't fit well with the SE model. Additionally, your last question is purely opinion based and needs to be removed.

Comment: "Radiation in home?" Really? Any properly designed UV system should fully contain /block the UV. If you install the system and you can see purple light coming out the ducts, it's junk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore the assumption that installing a UV system will improve the air quality of your home (it might or might not).

#### Buying a new system to have it include a UV system would be a waste of money.

Your system is well within its useful life, early replacement for this reason would not be wise.  If you must have this feature, an add-on is a much better option.